# React js add filter

Tags: reactjs, filter

I want to add a filter in arrays of filters, but all filters are added in the same array in filters. There are some blocks for filters and every filter must be added in its array. Now, every filter is added in its array, but all other filters are updated in that array too.

```
export const DropDownBlock = () => {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
    type: [],
    license: [],
    tag: [],
    format: [],
  });

  const filterKey = Object.keys(item.filters);

  const [checked, setChecked] = useState([]);

  return (
    <section className="filterSection">
      {filterKey.map((f, index) => {
        const filterArray = [];
        const photoItems = photos.map((p) => {
          return p.filters[filterKey[index]];
        });
        photoItems.map((p) => {
          if (filterArray.indexOf(p) < 0) {
            filterArray.push(p);
          }
        });

        const handleFilters = (filters, category) => {
          const newFilters = { ...filters };
          newFilters[category] = filters;

          setFilters(newFilters);
        };

        return (
          <div className="" key={f}>
            <div
              className="dropDownTitleBlock"
              onClick={() => (isOpen ? setIsOpen(false) : setIsOpen(true))}
            >
              {isOpen ? <MdKeyboardArrowDown /> : <MdKeyboardArrowRight />}
              <h5 className="dropDownTitle">{f}</h5>
            </div>

            {isOpen && (
              <div className="dropDownCategoryBlock">
                {filterArray.map((filter) => {
                  switch (f) {
                    case filterKey[index]:
                      return (
                        <Checkbox
                          filter={filter}
                          handleFilters={(filters) =>
                            handleFilters(filters, filterKey[index])
                          }
                          checked={checked}
                          setChecked={setChecked}
                        />
                      );
                  }
                })}
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </section>
  );
};
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I have some filter sections for image gallery... Can you give me any example about react filters for some filters block?